# Passing only coordinates on click “.ie. remove text” using Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Below is my map script, everything is working pretty fantastic! However, when I click and it sends the e.latlng to the form it is sending

LatLng(38.47939, -105.86426) for example. I would prefer that it only send 38.47939, -105.86426.

How can I remove the text and parentheses?

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([38.47939, -99.49219], 5);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYnJldHQyMjI3OCIsImEiOiJjajAzNzZjZTkwOWNtMzJxbHZjMmVwZ2hyIn0.cWzkt6Gj_N3SZ8GKzqhByA', {
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
    document.getElementById('lat-lng').value = e.latlng.toString();
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("Copy and Paste into the Form \n" + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);

    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);


</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e.latlng is a [LatLng](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#latlng) object and has properties (lat, lng)

So your code could be

```
.setContent("Copy and Paste into the Form \n" + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
```

You may want to format your values and only keep 6 digits

```
e.latlng.lat.toFixed(6);
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much! That is super helpful :)